# Removing non-ascii and special character in pyspark dataframe column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am reading data from csv files which has about 50 columns, few of the columns(4 to 5) contain text data with non-ASCII characters and special characters.

```
df = spark.read.csv(path, header=True, schema=availSchema)
```

I am trying to remove all the non-Ascii and special characters and keep only English characters, and I tried to do it as below

```
df = df['textcolumn'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii')
```

There are no spaces in my column name. I receive an error

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1486957561378215> in <module>
----> 1 InvFilteredDF = InvFilteredDF['SearchResultDescription'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii')

TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

Is there an alternative to accomplish this, appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Did my solution work?

Comment: @RahulP: Worked like a gem. Thanks so much. i upvoted the answer. I am new to big data and spark, and learning from passionate people like you :)

Comment: Welcome to big data and spark and thank you :) . If you feel that the answer is what you are looking for, could you please "accept" it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work.

First creating a temporary example dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "This is Spark"),
    (1, "I wish Java could use case classes"),
    (2, "Data science is  cool"),
    (3, "This is ï»¿aSA")
], ["id", "words"])

df.show()
```

**Output**

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|               words|
+---+--------------------+
|  0|       This is Spark|
|  1|I wish Java could...|
|  2|Data science is  ...|
|  3|      This is ï»¿aSA|
+---+--------------------+
```

Now to write a UDF because those functions that you use cannot be directly performed on a column type and you will get the `Column object not callable error`

**Solution**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def ascii_ignore(x):
    return x.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')

ascii_udf = udf(ascii_ignore)

df.withColumn("foo", ascii_udf('words')).show()
```

**Output**

```
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|               words|                 foo|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|  0|       This is Spark|       This is Spark|
|  1|I wish Java could...|I wish Java could...|
|  2|Data science is  ...|Data science is  ...|
|  3|      This is ï»¿aSA|         This is aSA|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this, saved me so much time when dealing with the dreaded zero width non-breaking space special character

Answer (score 5):

This answer worked well for me but it doesn't like NULL. I added a small mod:

```
def ascii_ignore(x):
  if x:
    return x.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
  else:
    return None
```

Answer (score 2):

Both answers are really useful, but I couldn't help but notice that we could just add `udf` as a decorator and be more pythonic

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf
def ascii_ignore(x):
    return x.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii') if x else None

df.withColumn("foo", ascii_ignore('words')).limit(5).show()
```